# Change views items per page dynamically

Tags: 7, views, paging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I limit the number of Views results on specific pages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29525/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-views-results-on-specific-pages)

I have a view that I use for showing different items on my website. It is a very simple view that accept taxonomy term as argument and shows the related nodes.

This view also have a pager, that handle 20 items per page.

I want to see if it is possible to dynamically change that to another number, for example if we are in different category (taxonomy term), I want to show different items per page.

I have tried achieving this by **hook_views_pre_build** or **hook_views_pre_execute** but no chances yet!

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 3.

Anyone can help please?